# Fit image on ImageButton

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I'm doing a TicTacToe in Android. When I click over an ImageButton, the image that displays the app enlarges the component, without respect the size of the button.

[image: TicTacToe]

I used the attribute `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` (almost `fitXY`, `centerInside`, `fitCenter`, `fitStart`) to try to fit the image inside the component, but it didn't work.

This is one part of my `XML` code of my ImageButton:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.246"
            android:onClick="onDonGato"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.246"
            android:onClick="onDonGato"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.246"
            android:onClick="onDonGato"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm not consider the Android device where I running the app (because I ran the game on an Android Virtual Device and it happens the same problem).

I'll appreciate any help to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the orientation of linear layout is horizontal then while setting weight to its child, you should set its width="0dp" and for vertical orientation height=0dp. and use fitXY.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.246"
            android:onClick="onDonGato"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.246"
            android:onClick="onDonGato"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.246"
            android:onClick="onDonGato"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:text="" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot fit an image centered in an image button... the options you have are center  on top of the text, on the bottom, and to left and right of the text...

I recommend you to switch to `ImageView` instead of Image button... and create a style for it to have the same effect as a button.

Other option would be to do it through a `GridView` with and `ImageView` inside but that's more unnecessary work...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a background image and set height and width.